# Kotlin take x elements from list but remove smallest number first

Tags: list, sorting, kotlin

So imagine you have a class `Product`. In this class, there is a `mutablelistOf<Stock>()`. The class `Stock` contains two properties: One property is the `quantity` the stock has and the other is the `amount of stars`. The `mutabeListOf<Stock>()` is sorted by the `amount of stars` ascending (first Stock in the list has 1 star, then 2 then 3...).

Now there is a customer who wants to take 5 items out of the Product list (the customer reduces the quantity property). The customer should take the items from the `Stock` with the *least amount of stars* **first**. 
As written above, the Stock with the least amount of stars is at the beginning of the list. After the customer took those 5 items the quantity property of the Stock object should be reduced **and** the object should be removed out of the list, when its quantity property is 0.

Another case would be when there are not enough items to be taken (e.g the customer wants 15 items but there are a total of 10). In this case, the maximum amount should be taken (10) and the amount the customer took should be returned (e.g here 10).

I know how to remove the items but when I remove them, the amount goes under 0 and the for loop does not "jump" to the next Stockobject.

Here is my current approach: Class Stock

```
class Stock(var quantity: Int, val stars: Int) {
    init {
        if (quantity < 0) quantity = 0
    }
}
```

Class Product and the function takeItems:

```
class Product {
    private val stockList = mutableListOf<Stock>()
    val availableItems: Double
        get() {
            return stockList.map { it.quantity.toDouble() }.sum()
        }

    fun addStock(item: Stock) = stockList.add(item)
    fun enoughItemsAvailable(itemQuantity: Int): Boolean = availableItems >= itemQuantity

    // The function I am trying to create to take items out of the list
    fun takeItems(quantity: Int): Int {
        stockList.sortBy { it.stars }

        var taken = 0
        for (i in stockList.indices) {
            if (stockList[i].quantity == 0) stockList.removeAt(i)
            if (enoughItemsAvailable(quantity)) {
                do {
                    stockList[i].quantity -= quantity
                    taken++
                } while (stockList[i].quantity > 0 || taken != quantity)
            } else {
                // when there is not enough items to be taken
                stockList.clear()
                return quantity
            }
        }
        return taken
    }
```

I hope you guys understood my problem. I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are taking the full requested quantity from the first stock in the list, even if that results in it having a negative quantity. I think you should have put `stockList[i].quantity--` instead of `stockList[i].quantity -= quantity`, because your strategy seems to be to remove one at a time.

Also, your first line in the loop removes a Stock if it's empty, and then the next part starts removing from the following Stock without first checking if it's empty. What if two Stocks in a row are empty? So the first `if` should be a `while`.

But since you are removing from the list while iterating its indices, you will reach an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if any items are removed. So you need to add `if (i >= stockList.size) break` at the beginning of your loop.

Your check for having enough items to satisfy the full request could be moved outside the loop to avoid redundantly checking for that condition over and over.

I think a simpler strategy is to walk through the list, taking as much as you need from each `Stock` until you've taken enough or exhausted the list. Then remove the empty Stocks in the list with one line. This way, you don't need a separate branch of logic for the case where there won't be enough to satisfy the request, and you don't need to separately check if any Stocks are already empty.

```
fun takeItems(quantity: Int): Int {
    stockList.sortBy { it.stars }

    var taken = 0
    for (stock in stockList) {
        val toRemove = min(quantity - taken, stock.quantity)
        taken += toRemove
        stock.quantity -= toRemove
        if (quantity == taken) break
    }

    stockList.removeAll { it.quantity == 0 }

    return taken
}
```

By the way, it looks like `availableItems` should be an `Int`, not `Double`, since it is a count of items. It could be more efficiently done with

```
    val availableItems: Int
        get() = stockList.sumBy(Stock::quantity)
```

since using `map` creates a new list every time this property is accessed.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works exactly like it should. But I don't know why. How does this ```min(quantity - taken, stock.quantity)``` work and is there a way to solve my problem without using ```min()```? Could you maybe explain your function a bit so I know how it works? Thank you

Comment: `min` returns whichever one of the two values is smaller. From each stock, you either want to remove all of the stock's quantity or however much you have left to satisfy `quantity`, whichever is less. There are many ways to solve the problem. Your way without `min` should work if you apply my corrections.